# saving files to cocoahttpserver in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoahttpserver

I need to download a file from an url and save it to local cocoahttpserver I have in my iphone app so that later i can access it using something like http://localhost/filename.txt

I have the cocoahttpserver code. But I am unable to figure out how to save files to it.
Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure both your file's download directory and the http server to access your app's Documents directory.

Comment: The server's document root is the Documents directory of iphone. But how do I access it with a url? I tried http://127.0.0.1:<someport>/filename.txt 
I even tried substituting the local ip and the internet ip address, but it doesn't get the file.